# Using _AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY property in ACTIVEMQ for scheduled messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I am trying to figure out a way to delay the message delivery. I came across [RabbitMQ Delayed Message](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/) plugin, as it is in experimental phase I was looking for other options.

From [here](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/scheduled-messages.html), I see that we can set `_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY` property to delay the message, but that does not seem to work.

Here is the producer and consumer code (taken from [here](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html)).

```
public static class HelloWorldProducer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Create a ConnectionFactory
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");

            // Create a Connection
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            // Create a Session
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

            // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

            // Create a messages
            String text = "Hello world! From: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + this.hashCode();
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

            // Tell the producer to send the message
            System.out.println("Sent message At: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            message.setLongProperty("_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000);
            producer.send(message);

            // Clean up
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
 public static class HelloWorldConsumer implements Runnable, ExceptionListener {
    public void run() {
        try {

            // Create a ConnectionFactory
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");

            // Create a Connection
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            connection.setExceptionListener(this);

            // Create a Session
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

            // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

            // Wait for a message
            Message message = consumer.receive(40000);

            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                String text = textMessage.getText();
                System.out.println("Received: " + text + " at: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Received: " + message);
            }

            consumer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But the message is being delivered instantly :

```
Sent message At: Mon Sep 14 17:37:01 IST 2015
Received: Hello world! From: Thread-0 : 746036857 at: Mon Sep 14 17:37:01 IST 2015
```

From the above link it's clear that ActiveMQ supports scheduling individual messages with different delays but I was able to figure out a way to do it correctly.

Also any insight into comparison of RabbitMQ's delayed message support against ActiveMQ's support is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ broker does support delayed message delivery but not using the same properties as Rabbit, a google search for the docs would have shown this pretty easily.  For future reference the documentation for this feature is here:

http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html

Comment: `_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY` is actually ActiveMQ's property, not RabbitMQ's.

Comment: Read the documentation or look at the source code and you'll find that it isn't

Comment: It is part of ActiveMQ Artemis, not ActiveMQ. Yeah, this naming is really confusing. To add to the confusion, ActiveMQ Artemis calls its client API classes like this: `ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` (part of `activemq.artemis` package, but you usually look at class name not package name). Also, some products which embed ActiveMQ Artemis, like JBoss EAP/Wildfly, refer to it only as 'messaging-activemq' in [config files/cli](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Messaging+configuration)